# How to read and write data of a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#

I'm making a lotto array game where I'm supposed to write 10 different numbers in to the array and see if I get a bingo. I want it to be 2 dimensional and I have got most of the code right (I have tried it in 1D) but just as I change it to be 2D, I get a problem with the array (array[i]) and I don´t know why.

Here is the code

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace kents.lottospel
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {

             Random rand = new Random();
             int randNum = rand.Next(1, 20);

             Console.WriteLine("skriv in nummer");
       
             for(var i= 0; i < 2; i++)
             {
                 for(var j= 0; j < 5; j++)
                 {
                     array[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                     if (array[i, j] == randNum) //and this is also 
 one problem (array[i])
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine($"Bing!\nDet rätta talet 
 var" + " " + randNum);
                         break;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine($"tyvärr men du har inte 
 fått nån bingo denna gången");
                     }
                 }
             }
                 Console.WriteLine("skriv in lottoboll nummer" + " 
 " + i + ":");
                 


             Console.WriteLine($"boll nummer" + " " + randNum + " " 
 + "gav bingo");
             Console.WriteLine("slut på spelet.");

         }

     }

 }
```

Comment: A 2-dimentional array needs to be indexed with 2 values

Comment: I kept telling you to ADD the new code. That didn't mean delete the old code. Now we have lost the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of a 2D array is that it has two dimensions. To access an element, you must specify the index in each dimension. That means that you can't use a single `for` loop to traverse it either. You generally use two nested `for` loops, e.g.

```cs
for (var i = 0; i <= myArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j <= myArray.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        // Use myArray[i, j] here.
    }
}
```

It's also up to you to make sure that you are consistent with regards to what's a "row" and what's a "column", as they are not explicit in a 2D array.

To be a bit more explicit, here's an example of setting each element in a 2D array and then getting each element:

```cs
var myArray = new long[10, 10];

for (var i = 0; i <= myArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j <= myArray.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        myArray[i, j] = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= myArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j <= myArray.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("({0},{1}): {2}", i, j, myArray[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain a little more? sorry im really new in coding and haven´t worked om arrays before and neither nested for loops...

Comment: @KentKarlsson, think of an Excel spreadsheet. Would you know what cell I was talking about if I just gave you a row number or just a column name? Of course you wouldn't. You need both. A 2D array is just like that. How would you traverse every cell in a sheet? You'd visit every column in a row, then every column in the next row and so on. That's nested loops. The logic that you live your life by doesn't change because you're implementing it in code. A 2D array is basically just a table/grid so you treat just like you would any other table/grid.

Comment: im having problem now that i have been trying to fix, and it´s that the array in array[i, j] is not in context and i do´t know how to make it in to context... i switched the coding to so that the Random rand is before the for(var i=o; etc. And i also put the IF and ELSE statements into the for loop, because it felt like the most logical thing.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. If you have changed your code in an attempt to implement the solution and failed then we need to see the new code. Edit your question and add the new code and a specific explanation of the new issue. If you had simply replaced your existing loop with these nested loops then it would have worked, so you must have done something weird and we're not likely to guess what that was.

Comment: this is the changes i did to the code https://imgur.com/HaEbuK8 , i didn´t know what else i should have done, because im studying on distance im not getting help from any teachers and the book i have doesn´t explain anything on making a vector or a array with a after input/random input. so that´s why im coming here for my questions.

Comment: @KentKarlsson, you need to edit your question and not provide pictures of code. Add the new code to your question and we can take a look.

Comment: i have edit in the new code in the question so that you can see the new code. thanks of the help

Comment: @KentKarlsson, you're not actually creating an array anywhere in that new code. My answer assumes that you have already created an array and assigned it to a variable named `myArray`. The point of that example variable name is to indicate that it is your array. You should use a different name appropriate to your specific scenario. If you want to set or get an element in an array, you have to have an array first.

Comment: I have added a longer code sample. Note that this question was about accessing elements in a 2D array so the discussion should not go beyond that subject. If you need help with your assignment beyond that, make sure that you ask a new question specifically about a new problem.

Comment: thanks so much for the help, i hope i will solve it with out any more help

Answer (score 2):

With a two dimensional array, you need two different values to index into it. If you only specify a single value for the index with a 2D jagged array for example, the result will be another array, not a single integer value:

```
//This will be an int[]
var subArray = array[0]

//This will be an int
var element = array[0][0]
```

When you are reading input values from the console, you are only specifying one index value for the array so that expression boils down to something like this:

```
int[] array = new array[5];
array = 42; //compiler error
```

To populate a 2D array, you will need to change your loop to be a nested one. The outer loop will iterate over the first dimension and the inner loop will iterate over the second dimension:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        array[i,j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine(...));
    }
}
```

Comment: *"If you only specify a single value for the index with a 2D array, the result will be another array, not a single integer value"*. That is false. You cannot use a single index with a 2D array. You are confusing it with a jagged array. A 2D array is a single object where all elements are peers, while a jagged array is an array of arrays, so you can index the outer array to access one of the inner arrays.

Comment: Indeed. Got my multidimensional arrays mixed up with jagged arrays. I'll add a note to the answer to clarify that